# How to get a consistent zigzag line?

Tags: pstricks, pst-coil

I want to get a consistent zigzag line that will be used to mimic a physical spring.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-coil,multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPset\CoilArm{.2}
\FPset\Windings{7}

\psset
{
    coilarm=\CoilArm,
    linejoin=1,
}

\def\System#1#2{% #1: total length includes the arms, #2: coil width
    \FPeval\CoilWidth{trunc(#2,9)}%
    \FPeval\CoilHeight{trunc((#1-2*CoilArm)/(CoilWidth*Windings),9)}%
    \pszigzag[coilwidth=\CoilWidth,coilheight=\CoilHeight](1,0)(1,-#1)%
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(13,-7)
\multido{\nx=0+1.25,\nl=2.50+.50,\nw=1.00+-0.10}{10}{\rput(\nx,0){\System{\nl}{\nw}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

In the figure below, the red cross represents inconsistent zigzag lines as its top end begins with a different orientation of segment.

[image]

I have increased the precision of `trunc` by choosing a large number of digit. But it does not seem to work. How to solve this issue?

### Facts

One method to get rid of this inconsistency is by choosing a constant `coilwidth`. However, with constant `coilwidth` the animation will not look realistic anymore. That is the problem.

Comment: The orientation seems to be consistent at the end of the coil. So, you could reverse the coil drawing. However, my guess is your question will then change to request a consistent coil from either end...

Comment: @Werner: Yes. I know that but they are still inconsistent and it will make a bad animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last resort: don't rely on `pst-coil`!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPset\CoilArm{.6}
\FPset\Windings{7}

\def\System#1#2{% #1: total length includes the arms, #2: coil width
    \FPeval\CoilWidth{#2}%
    \FPeval\Lambda{(#1-2*CoilArm)/Windings}%
    \FPeval\PlotPoints{trunc(4*Windings+1,0)}%
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\PlotPoints,algebraic]{0}{\Lambda\space \Windings\space mul}{\CoilWidth*sin(2*Pi*t/\Lambda)|-t-\CoilArm}{P}%
    \pscustom[linejoin=1]
    {
        \psline(0,0)
        \psnline(0,\Pnodecount){P}
        \psline(0,-#1)
    }%
    \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(13,-7)
\multido{\nx=1.00+1.25,\nl=2.50+.50,\nw=.50+-.05}{10}{\rput(\nx,0){\System{\nl}{\nw}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\CoilWidth` which is used as the amplitude must be kept positive to avoid getting inconsistent zigzag. It might be the source of problem in `pszigzag` (just my hypothesis).