# Add a "spring" symbol above a character

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to add a symbol that looks like a (compressed) spring "\/\/\" (this is just to give a rough idea; I want the lines to be connected) above a character (in math mode). Any ideas on how to do this? (The comprehensive list doesn't seem to have such a symbol.)

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `\lfilet` of `mathabx`, but horizontal?

Comment: [Table 303: Miscellaneous stix Math Symbols](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf): `\hzigzag`?

Comment: @corey979: Not bad! Thank you! Though I'd prefer a sharper zigzag.

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104072/tikz-custom-zigzag-pattern) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151575/how-to-get-a-consistent-zigzag-line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired from this question, [Change vertical space in overset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194798/change-vertical-space-in-overset) you  can add a ''spring'' symbol above a character.

With `\gluon` symbol. 
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[\overset{\lower.3em\hbox{\,\scaleobj{.4}{\gluon}}}{A}\]
\end{document}
```

With `\photon` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\[\overset{\lower.1em\hbox{\,\scalebox{.5}[2.1]{\photon}}}{A}\]
\end{document}
```